# Return response from API as inner JSON objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use this code to get a list of countries as full name and ISO code:

```
public Map<String, Object> getCountryNameCodeList() {

        String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
        Map<String, Object> list = new HashMap<>();

        for (String countryCode : countryCodes) {

            Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

            list.put(obj.getDisplayCountry().toString(), obj.getCountry());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Rest API:

```
@GetMapping("shipping_countries")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getShippingCountries() {

    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(countriesService.getCountryNameCodeList(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I get the response data in this format:

```
{
    "Papua New Guinea": "PG",
    "Cambodia": "KH",
    "Kazakhstan": "KZ",
    "Paraguay": "PY",
    .....
}
```

I would like to get the data this way:

```
[
  {
    name: "Papua New Guinea",
    value: "PG"
  },
  {
    name: "Unites States",
    value: "US"
  }, 
  ....
]
```

How I can modify the Java code to return the data this way?

Comment: You have to use DTO to send custom response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach. You need to use data transfer object to return customized data.

Create a class DTO.

```
public class DTO {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DTO [key=" + key + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

}
```

Create Rest API in the controller. Example :

```
@RestController
public class Sample {

    @RequestMapping("shipping_countries")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DTO>> getShippingCountries() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Papua New Guinea", "PG");
        map.put("Cambodia", "KH");
        List<DTO> list = getCustomisedData(map);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
    }

    private List<DTO> getCustomisedData(Map<String, String> map) {
        List<DTO> dtos = new ArrayList();
        for(Entry<String, String> value: map.entrySet()) {
            DTO dto = new DTO();
            dto.setKey(value.getKey());
            dto.setValue(value.getValue());
            dtos.add(dto);
        }
        return dtos;
    }
}
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The response you are getting is the `JSON` representation of a map, which is what you return.
The `json` you want is an array of objects, so if you want to return that- the easiest way will be to return it like that, is to return the set of `Map.Entry` from your map. Something like that:

```
@GetMapping("shipping_countries")
public ResponseEntity<Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>>> getShippingCountries() {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(countriesService.getCountryNameCodeList().entrySet(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Other way can be to create a `Json` `serializer` for the response, but it seems like an overkill

Comment: I have partial success. I get a response like this   https://pastebin.com/nc8zNxGz How I can add `name` and  `value` keys?

Comment: You can create a class with `name` and `value` fields and convert your map to a list of it